# Step by step guide for upgrading Typo3 from 6.1 to 6.2

Tags: typo3-6.2.x, typo3-6.1.x

I'm completely new to Typo3 and have inherited a live Typo3 6.1 website. 
I have spent a good while researching for 6.1 > 6.2 upgrade guides, but have found nothing so far.

From what I have inderstood, earlier versions just required the overwriting of "t3lib", "typo3" and "index.php" and then possibly some DB adjustments using the BE Upgrade Wizard.

However, there is no 6.2 blank package any more. Just the source file...

Can anybody give (or recommend) a simple step by step upgrade guide from 6.1 to 6.2?

Just to note, I will have to do everything manually (FTP) - no symlinks and no SSH.

Thanks, R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download TYPO3 6.2. source and replace the `typo3` folder and `index.php` file, next go to Install Tool and process upgrade wizard steps. That's all. `t3lib` folder can be deleted after all it's not used anymore in TYPO3 6.2 (all sources are now in `typo3`)

**IMPORTANT**: make a full copy of site (files+DB) before any changes.

Honestly doing it via FTP is nervous operation - especially when using with unstable net connection it would be best to do changes via SSH or at least with some tool allowing for remote unpacking and renaming files, so you can make a copy just on the server.

Most probably Install tool will claim about not using symlinks, but' that's rather cosmetic requirement and your installation will work well without them.